# Karabiner Elements - CTRL+HOME and CTRL+END to go to beginning or end of document

Tags: keyboard, karabiner

I am accustomed to using CTRL+HOME or CTRL+END to quickly navigate to the beginning or end of a document respectively; however, I cannot seem to get that working in karabiner elements.

I have come across CMD+Up and CMD+Down to go to the beginning or end of a web page, but that doesn't seem to work in VS Code or others.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> are beginning and end of file according to VS Code documentation.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/shortcuts/keyboard-shortcuts-macos.pdf linked from **Help >> Keyboard Shortcuts Reference** (also available via <kbd>⌘K</kbd> <kbd>⌘R</kbd>).